# How to capture stream from mediaklikk.hu?

Tags: video-capture

I want to capture a streaming video from mediaklikk.hu. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this even legal?

Answer (score 2):

- Start to play the video
- Open Google Chrome's Developer Tools' Network tab
- Search for `playlist.m3u8`, click on the item's URL and copy the Request URL
- In VLC, select File > Open Network...
- Paste the URL
- To capture the whole stream:

  - Check Streaming/saving, click Settings... and choose the output file
  - Click Open and VLC will start capturing
- To capture a part of the stream:

  - Click Open
  - Navigate to 4-5 seconds before the desired part
  - Select Playback > Record

Answer (score 2):

#### alternative solution for the commandline zsh and curl (Linux/Mac)

**idea**: collect all the video parts and paste them into one file, can run in a shell in background, you have to know the **starting url** and the **number of pieces**

- got to Chrome developer tools - network tab
- when the stream starts you see an url like:
  `media_w415294746_b800000_1.ts?keys=h9bDPql-rzDe-44uEorcTA&keyt=1457916109`
- the `_b8000000` stands for the video quality, so `_b12000000` is better/bigger
- the number before `.ts` stands for the video part
- fast forward to the end of the video and get the last number, eg. 444
- copy url of a video part with right mouse menu / copy link address
- now get all the part in commend line with the tool `curl`
- use a loop from 1..444 with variable i - in url change the number into eg `_1.ts` into `_${i}.ts`
- paste alle the video parts into one file myvideo.mp4 using `>>`
- in command line use zsh (runs in Linux or MacOS)

  ```
  for i in {1..444}; do echo "* video part $i ..."; curl URL >> myvideo.mp4; done
  ```
- when you paste your URL at the place of URL be aware to escape special characters eg. `=&?` with `\`

working example:

```
zsh> for i in {1..444}; do echo "* video part $i ..."; curl http://212.40.98.161/intvod/_definst_/r/mtva/2016/02/26/2016-000128-M0054-01-/international.smil/media_w415294746_b1200000_${i}.ts\?keys\=h9bDPql-rzDe-44uEorcTA\&keyt\=1457916109 >> mymovie.mp4; done
```

now you should see some output like this:

```
* video part 1 ...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1441k  100 1441k    0     0   486k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  486k
* video part 2 ...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1438k  100 1438k    0     0   475k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  475k
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! One minor comment: in my case, the numbering of the parts started from 0 instead of 1.